# bad request error 400 while using python requests.post function

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-post, python-requests, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to make a simple post request via the requests library of Python and I get a bad request error (400) while my url is supposedly correct since I can use it to perform a get.
I'm very new in REST requests, I read many tutorials and documentation but I guess there are still things I don't get so my error could be basic. Maybe a lack of understanding on the type of url I'm supposed to send via POST. Here my code :

```
import requests
v_username = "username"
v_password = "password"
v_headers = {'content-type':'application/rdf+xml'}
url = 'https://my.url'
params = {'param': 'val_param'}
payload = {'data': 'my_data'}
r = requests.post(url, params = params, auth=(v_username, v_password), data=payload, headers=v_headers, verify=False)
print r
```

I used the example of the requests documentation.

Comment: The 400 error is generated by the server; `requests` did its job just fine. There is nothing we can help you with here.

Comment: That Content-Type header is nonsense. When you pass a dictionary to the `data` argument, Requests builds and sends that data as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Why are you setting it?

Comment: Well, it's the header I used to use when making Get requests so I thought it would work the same for a Put. I don't understand what I should do then, merge my data and my header in the same dictionary ?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, i tried changing params to data or with json.dumps():

```
from json import dumps

r = requests.post(url, params=dumps(params), auth=(v_username, v_password), data=payload, headers=v_headers, verify=False)
```

or

```
r = requests.post(url, data=dumps(params), auth=(v_username, v_password), data=payload, headers=v_headers, verify=False)
```

Comment: *json.dumps(params)